# PL/SQL Procedure to create XML

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm very inexperienced with PL/SQL, and am tasked with creating a procedure that use need two parameters and create XML for my current select statement. I have bits and pieces of it, but am having trouble finding how to put it all together.

So I know I will need to start with the following:

```
PROCEDURE markviewimport_interface c_markviewimport.invoice_id NUMBER(10) = NULL c_markviewimport.filename nvarchar(30) = NULL
```

And I know that I will need a cursor in order to gather the data line by line.

```
CURSOR c_markviewimport IS SELECT DISTINCT inv.invoice_id, 
                        vendor.segment1 vendor_num, 
                        vendor.vendor_name, 
                        poh.segment1    PO_NUMBER, 
                        inv.invoice_date, 
                        inv.invoice_num, 
                        terms.name      TERMS_NAME, 
                        inv.invoice_amount, 
                        inv.amount_applicable_to_discount, 
                        inv.amount_paid, 
                        pmt.check_date  PAYMENT_DATE, 
                        path.filename, 
                        path.complete_filename, 
                        path.document_id, 
                        stamps.text, 
                        stamps.tool_name 
        FROM   apps.ap_invoices_all inv, 
               apps.ap_invoice_distributions_all dist, 
               apps.po_distributions_all podi, 
               apps.ap_invoice_payment_history_v pmt, 
               apps.fnd_attached_docs_form_vl fnd, 
               markview.mv_page_image_paths path, 
               apps.po_vendors vendor, 
               apps.po_headers_all poh, 
               apps.ap_terms terms, 
               (SELECT mp.document_id, 
                       moi.markup_object_id, 
                       moi.page_markups_view_id, 
                       moi.text, 
                       mvt.tool_name, 
                       mp.page_id 
                FROM   markview.mv_markup_object moi, 
                       markview.mv_tool mvt, 
                       markview.mv_page_markups_view mpmv, 
                       markview.mv_page mp 
                WHERE  moi.tool_id = mvt.tool_id 
                       AND mp.page_id = mpmv.page_id 
                       AND mpmv.page_markups_view_id = moi.page_markups_view_id 
                       AND mvt.tool_id IN (SELECT mvt.tool_id 
                                           FROM   markview.mv_tool 
                                           WHERE  mvt.tool_name IN ( 
                           'Green Text', 'Blue Sticky Note' ) 
                                          )) stamps 
        WHERE  inv.invoice_id = To_number(fnd.pk1_value) 
               AND inv.invoice_id = dist.invoice_id 
               AND poh.po_header_id(+) = podi.po_header_id 
               AND podi.po_distribution_id(+) = dist.po_distribution_id 
               AND fnd.file_name = To_char(path.document_id) 
               AND inv.invoice_id = pmt.invoice_id 
               AND path.document_id = stamps.document_id(+) 
               AND path.page_id = stamps.page_id(+) 
               AND fnd.category_description = 'MarkView Document' 
               AND fnd.entity_name = 'AP_INVOICES' 
               AND INV.vendor_id = poh.vendor_id(+) 
               AND INV.terms_id = TERMS.term_id 
               AND inv.vendor_id = vendor.vendor_id 
               AND path.platform_name = 'UNIX_FS_TO_DOC_SERVER' 
               AND pmt.void = 'N') r_markviewimport
```

And lastly this is what I'm using for XML that contains every column I need.

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("Item", Xmlforest(r_markviewimport.invoice_id, 
       r_markviewimport.vendor_num, r_markviewimport.vendor_name, 
       r_markviewimport.po_number, 
       r_markviewimport.invoice_date, r_markviewimport.invoice_num, 
       r_markviewimport.terms_name, r_markviewimport.invoice_amount, 
       r_markviewimport.amount_applicable_to_discount, 
       r_markviewimport.amount_paid, 
       r_markviewimport.payment_date, 
       r_markviewimport.filename, r_markviewimport.complete_filename, 
       r_markviewimport.document_id, r_markviewimport.text, 
       r_markviewimport.tool_name 
       )) "Item Element"
```

I guess I just need help, or pointed in the right direction for creating this procedure and putting it all together.

Comment: Also, if anyone would tell me what kind of terminology that I am probably using wrong, feel free to tell me so I will know in the future. Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to get the XML back? You're creating a procedure, so it won't return anything like a function would. Are you inserting the XML into a table, or writing it to a file or something?

Comment: I am wanting to write it to a file on one of our Unix servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There are several ways](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB4987) to generate XML from tables in Oracle.

The main benefit to using the SQL functions (like XMLELEMENT and XMLFOREST) is that you **don't** have to iterate over a cursor line-by-line - you can do all the work in one query. Conversely, if you want to do it row-by-row with a cursor like that, using DBMS_XMLGEN would probably make more sense. You might want to do that if you have a lot of changes to make to the data before writing it to XML.

Here's a procedure to do it with XML SQL functions.

```
create or replace procedure markviewimport_interface (p_invoice_id number(10), p_filename nvarchar(30))
is
    v_output clob;
begin

    SELECT XMLELEMENT("Items", XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("Item", Xmlforest(r_markviewimport.invoice_id, 
       r_markviewimport.vendor_num, r_markviewimport.vendor_name, 
       r_markviewimport.po_number, 
       r_markviewimport.invoice_date, r_markviewimport.invoice_num, 
       r_markviewimport.terms_name, r_markviewimport.invoice_amount, 
       r_markviewimport.amount_applicable_to_discount, 
       r_markviewimport.amount_paid, 
       r_markviewimport.payment_date, 
       r_markviewimport.filename, r_markviewimport.complete_filename, 
       r_markviewimport.document_id, r_markviewimport.text, 
       r_markviewimport.tool_name 
       )))).getclobval() into v_output
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT inv.invoice_id, 
                        vendor.segment1 vendor_num, 
                        vendor.vendor_name, 
                        poh.segment1    PO_NUMBER, 
                        inv.invoice_date, 
                        inv.invoice_num, 
                        terms.name      TERMS_NAME, 
                        inv.invoice_amount, 
                        inv.amount_applicable_to_discount, 
                        inv.amount_paid, 
                        pmt.check_date  PAYMENT_DATE, 
                        path.filename, 
                        path.complete_filename, 
                        path.document_id, 
                        stamps.text, 
                        stamps.tool_name 
        FROM   apps.ap_invoices_all inv, 
               apps.ap_invoice_distributions_all dist, 
               apps.po_distributions_all podi, 
               apps.ap_invoice_payment_history_v pmt, 
               apps.fnd_attached_docs_form_vl fnd, 
               markview.mv_page_image_paths path, 
               apps.po_vendors vendor, 
               apps.po_headers_all poh, 
               apps.ap_terms terms, 
               (SELECT mp.document_id, 
                       moi.markup_object_id, 
                       moi.page_markups_view_id, 
                       moi.text, 
                       mvt.tool_name, 
                       mp.page_id 
                FROM   markview.mv_markup_object moi, 
                       markview.mv_tool mvt, 
                       markview.mv_page_markups_view mpmv, 
                       markview.mv_page mp 
                WHERE  moi.tool_id = mvt.tool_id 
                       AND mp.page_id = mpmv.page_id 
                       AND mpmv.page_markups_view_id = moi.page_markups_view_id 
                       AND mvt.tool_id IN (SELECT mvt.tool_id 
                                           FROM   markview.mv_tool 
                                           WHERE  mvt.tool_name IN ( 
                           'Green Text', 'Blue Sticky Note' ) 
                                          )) stamps 
        WHERE  inv.invoice_id = To_number(fnd.pk1_value) 
               AND inv.invoice_id = dist.invoice_id 
               AND poh.po_header_id(+) = podi.po_header_id 
               AND podi.po_distribution_id(+) = dist.po_distribution_id 
               AND fnd.file_name = To_char(path.document_id) 
               AND inv.invoice_id = pmt.invoice_id 
               AND path.document_id = stamps.document_id(+) 
               AND path.page_id = stamps.page_id(+) 
               AND fnd.category_description = 'MarkView Document' 
               AND fnd.entity_name = 'AP_INVOICES' 
               AND INV.vendor_id = poh.vendor_id(+) 
               AND INV.terms_id = TERMS.term_id 
               AND inv.vendor_id = vendor.vendor_id 
               AND path.platform_name = 'UNIX_FS_TO_DOC_SERVER' 
               AND pmt.void = 'N') r_markviewimport;

    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file(v_output, 'MY_DIRECTORY', 'output.xml');
    --return v_output;

end markviewimport_interface;
/
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm starting to understand it more and more.